# To find the volume of the region that is bordered by 4 points in 3D space

Tags: matrices, 3d

To find the volume of the region that in the points $A(x_1,y_1,z_1),B(x_2,y_2,z_2),C(x_3,y_3,z_3),D(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Let's define a 4X4 matrix to determine plane equation  that are on $A,B,C$
$$\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}x & y & z& 1\\x_1 & y_1 & z_1& 1\\x_2 & y_2 & z_2& 1\\x_3 & y_3 & z_3& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

We know that plane equation can be found by $$det(\mathbf{M})=0$$ ,

Let's put $D(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to plane equation and to get :

$$\mathbf{M_{3}}=\begin{bmatrix}x_0 & y_0 & z_0& 1\\x_1 & y_1 & z_1& 1\\x_2 & y_2 & z_2& 1\\x_3 & y_3 & z_3& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

We know if the point $D$ is on the plane (A,B,C) , $det(\mathbf{M_3})=0$. The point will satisfy the plane equation but if it is not on the plane we will have a value.

Is it true that volume $V$ of the region that is bordered by 4 points can written as
$V=\frac{1}{3} |det(\mathbf{M_3})|$ ?

I wrote it as intuition without proof. Can you help me to prove the lemma ? (or disprove)

And more generally ; Can the region value that is bordered by ($n+1$) points in the n-dimensional space be calculated by
$V_n=\frac{1}{n} |det(\mathbf{M_{n}})|$ ?

Please note that if $n=2$ ,
 The formula satisfies to find the area of triangle in 2D space

$$\mathbf{M_{2}}=\begin{bmatrix}x_0 & y_0 & 1\\x_1 & y_1 & 1\\x_2 & y_2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$V_2=A=\frac{1}{2} |det(\mathbf{M_{2}})|$

Thanks for answers and comments

EDIT: I have found [the paper](ftp://www.cs.indiana.edu/pub/hanson/Siggraph01QuatCourse/ggndgeom.pdf) in web while googling. You can see the related part in page 154 about N-dimensional volume calculation. As @Christian Blatter  pointed, the numarical factor must be $1\over n!$  not $1\over n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $n+1$ points ${\bf a}_k$ $(0\leq k\leq n)$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$ one considers their convex hull $S$ which is a (maybe degenerate) $n$-dimensional *simplex*. This simplex is spanned by the $n$ vectors ${\bf a}_k-{\bf a}_0$ $(1\leq k\leq n)$, and its volume is equal to the volume of the parallelotope $P$ spanned by these vectors, divided by $n!$ (see below). The volume of $P$ is, up to sign,  equal to  the determinant of the matrix having the coordinates of the spanning vectors ${\bf a}_k-{\bf a}_0$ in its columns. So
$${\rm vol}(S)={1\over n!}\>\biggl|\det\bigl[{\bf a}_1-{\bf a}_0,\ {\bf a}_2-{\bf a}_0,\ \ldots,\ {\bf a}_n-{\bf a}_0\bigr]\biggr|\ .\tag{1}$$
Consider now your matrices $M_2$ and $M_3$. If you subtract the first row from all the other rows you obtain  matrices $\hat M_2$ and $\hat M_3$ whose last column is zero, apart from the element in the upper right corner, which remains $1$. It's easy to see that the determinants of $\hat M_2$, $\hat M_3$, and therefore the determinants of $M_2$ and $M_3$, coincide, up to sign,  with the determinant appearing in $(1)$. But your conjectured numerical factor is **wrong**.

I cannot see how the equations of the  hyperplanes bounding $S$ should play a rôle here.

A proof of $(1)$ rests on induction and an application of Fubini's theorem. For arbitrary $n\geq1$ consider the special simplex  with vertices ${\bf 0}$ and $h{\bf e}_k$ $(1\leq k\leq n)$:
$$S_n(h):=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\>|\>x_k\geq0 \ (1\leq k\leq n), \ x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n\leq h\}\ .$$
It is geometrically obvious that ${\rm vol}_n\bigl(S_n(h)\bigr)=h^n\>{\rm vol}_n\bigl(S_n(1)\bigr)$.
We now proceed as follows:
$$\eqalign{{\rm vol}_{n+1}\bigl(S_{n+1}(1)\bigr)&=\int_{S_{n+1}(1)} 1\ {\rm d}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\cr&=\int_0^1\left(\int_{S_n(1-x_{n+1})}1\ {\rm d}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\right)\>dx_{n+1}\cr &=\int_0^1{\rm vol}_n\bigl(S_n(1-x_{n+1})\bigr)\>dx_{n+1}\cr
&={\rm vol}_n\bigl(S_n(1)\bigr)\int_0^1(1-x_{n+1})^n\>dx_{n+1}\cr
&={1\over n+1}{\rm vol}_n\bigl(S_n(1)\bigr)\ .\cr}$$

Comment: I tested  the formula on a simple 4 points  examples such as $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ that $V=1/6$.It should be factorial factor as you said for $3D$. I missed that point but I wonder how to prove that it is true for higher dimensions. We cannot figure out in mind the higher dimensions than 3D,can we? How did they prove that? Do you know a related links or reference books for that subject? Thanks a lot for your help.